# Add validation class to parent element in angular 6 template driven form

Tags: angular, validation, angular2-directives

**Overview:**

I am trying to find a nice way to add a class to an inputs parent element

I currently have this code:

`<p [ngClass]="{'error' : prop.invalid  && (prop.dirty || prop.touched) }">
        <label>Prop Label</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.prop" #prop="ngModel" required />
</p>`

which works fine!

**Problem:**

I want to be able to do it in a more generic way i.e.

- using a directive to set the parent class (can't seem to find how to pass prop.invalid to it?)
- setting the parent element to receive the classes at a global level instead of the input

**Note:** I am not using reactive forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a custom attribute directive to the `<p>` element that will check it's child `<input>` validity.

Regarding the problems you've mentioned in your question:

- `using a directive to set the parent class`: use `Renderer2` class to add/remove `error` class to `<p>` element
- `(can't seem to find how to pass prop.invalid to it?)`: you'll get a reference to the `<input>` by using `@ContentChild`, finding it by `NgModel` class.
- `setting the parent element to receive the classes at a global level instead of the input`: not sure what is the problem, looks like the first one. add a comment to this answer if needed.

---

> [Live Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-validating-child)

These are the changes you need to make:

**HTML:**

```
<p requiredValidator>
    <label>Prop Label</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.prop" #prop="ngModel" required />
</p>
```

**Directive:**

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewChild, ContentChild, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[requiredValidator]'
})
export class RequiredValidatorDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  element: ElementRef;
  renderer: Renderer2;
  @ContentChild(NgModel) input: NgModel;

  constructor(element: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer2) {
    this.element = element;
    this.renderer = renderer;
  }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.input.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.input.invalid  && (this.input.dirty || this.input.touched)) {
        this.addErrorClass();
      } else {
        this.removeErrorClass();
      }
    })
  }

  addErrorClass(): void {
    this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'error');
  }

  removeErrorClass(): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, 'error');
  }
}
```